# Is it proper to request a specific paper here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am looking for an old paper; I clearly remember that I have found it a few years ago but could not find the paper anymore. Not sure if it is proper to ask here. Anyway, the paper I am looking for is

```
Goldsmith, Deborah Louise
Homotopy of braids—in answer to a question of E. Artin. 
Topology Conference 
(Virginia Polytech. Inst. and State Univ., Blacksburg, Va., 1973),
pp. 91–96. Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 375, Springer, Berlin, 1974.
```

But do let me know if it is improper to ask this type of question here.

Comment: Did you want to ask this on meta? (I.e., you are asking: *Is question like this allowed?*) Or maybe you wanted to ask on the main site. (So your question is where to find the paper.)

Comment: Related post on meta: [“Help me find a paper”-type questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/help-me-find-a-paper-type-questions)

Comment: Basically I am more interested in finding the specific paper mentioned. Not sure where should I look for it.

Comment: So it would be more appropriate to ask this on the main site. If your institution has access you can simply download it from the publisher; doi: [10.1007/BFb0064014](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0064014). If not you can try to find someone who has access and is willing to send you the article.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak! Just realize that my institution has access and I have already found the paper. Many thanks again for your kind assistance!

Comment: @MartinSleziak I apologize for my poor memory... After finding this paper and when I save it, I found a copy in my computer.

Comment: *Lame attempt for a joke:* Of course you found a copy in your computer. That's what saving a file does. *More seriously:* No harm done, such things happen.

Comment: If you don't know about it yet: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/ is a tremendously helpful tool for finding published papers, if you have access to it. Otherwise, simply typing the title of the paper in google works 75% of the time, I'd say (whether it's on arXiv or on someone's personal page).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my experience, it is certainly acceptable to ask for someone to summarize a narrow portion of a paper, eg. the proof of a Lemma or the requirements of a construction, or to help you locate a library resource that has the paper (if not available on-line).

However asking someone (other than the author) to send you an actual copy of a paper opens up some copyright issues that Math.SE should not be in the middle of, and there are also the logistical details of carrying out a delivery.  In addition this would fall into the category of "unlikely to benefit future readers".

I'm not trying to be the copyright police here, but I do think we can draw a useful line that should not be crossed.

Comment: On the other hand, if the question is phrased, for example, as *"How can I find an old article from LNM? Is it possible that they are available online?"* I'd think that such question would be ok. And if OP mentions in some question that they are not able to find some paper (in any kind of question), I would not see as a bad thing offering the paper to the OP. (I would prefer to do it per e-mail, outside the site, but most users don't advertise their e-mail address in the profile.) I've made similar points in [an answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17128/) to a related question.

Comment: Just to clarify: My comment was intended as a reaction to *"unlikely to benefit future readers"* and *copyright issues* in your post. I'll add that there have been some [meta-tag:copyright] related discussions on meta in the past. For example, [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/529/to-what-extent-should-copyrighted-material-be-made-available-on-math-se) seems relevant. (And maybe a few other posts.)